# Concurrently sum the inner dictionary in the Dict{Tuple, Dict{String,Int64}} in a single loop

Tags: dictionary, nested, tuples, julia

Given a countmap object that counts words in a text:

```
vocab_counter = countmap(split("the lazy fox jumps over the brown dog"))
```

[out]:

```
Dict{SubString{String},Int64} with 7 entries:
  "brown" => 1
  "lazy"  => 1
  "jumps" => 1
  "the"   => 2
  "fox"   => 1
  "over"  => 1
  "dog"   => 1
```

And to get a character bigram counter, per word:

```
ngram_word_counter = Dict{Tuple,Dict}()
for (word, count) in vocab_counter
    for ng in ngrams(word, n) # bigrams.
        if ! haskey(ngram_word_counter, ng) || ! haskey(ngram_word_counter[ng], word)
            ngram_word_counter[ng] = Dict{String,Int64}()
            ngram_word_counter[ng][word] = 0
        end
        ngram_word_counter[ng][word] += count
    end
end
```

[`ngram_word_counter`]:

```
Dict{Tuple,Dict} with 20 entries:
  ('b','r') => Dict("brown"=>1)
  ('t','h') => Dict("the"=>2)
  ('o','w') => Dict("brown"=>1)
  ('z','y') => Dict("lazy"=>1)
  ('o','g') => Dict("dog"=>1)
  ('u','m') => Dict("jumps"=>1)
  ('o','x') => Dict("fox"=>1)
  ('e','r') => Dict("over"=>1)
  ('a','z') => Dict("lazy"=>1)
  ('p','s') => Dict("jumps"=>1)
  ('h','e') => Dict("the"=>2)
  ('d','o') => Dict("dog"=>1)
  ('w','n') => Dict("brown"=>1)
  ('m','p') => Dict("jumps"=>1)
  ('l','a') => Dict("lazy"=>1)
  ('o','v') => Dict("over"=>1)
  ('v','e') => Dict("over"=>1)
  ('r','o') => Dict("brown"=>1)
  ('f','o') => Dict("fox"=>1)
  ('j','u') => Dict("jumps"=>1)
```

With the `Dict{Tuple, Dict{String,Int64}}` object, I would need to re-loop the `ngram_word_counter` to get the `ngram_counter` without the word, i.e. `Dict{Tuple,Int64}`:

```
ngram_counter = Dict{Tuple,Int64}()
for ng in keys(ngram_word_counter)
    ngram_counter[ng] = sum(values(ngram_word_counter[ng]))
end
```

[ngram_counter]:

```
Dict{Tuple,Int64} with 20 entries:
  ('b','r') => 1
  ('t','h') => 2
  ('o','w') => 1
  ('z','y') => 1
  ('o','g') => 1
  ('u','m') => 1
  ('o','x') => 1
  ('e','r') => 1
  ('a','z') => 1
  ('p','s') => 1
  ('h','e') => 2
  ('d','o') => 1
  ('w','n') => 1
  ('m','p') => 1
  ('l','a') => 1
  ('o','v') => 1
  ('v','e') => 1
  ('r','o') => 1
  ('f','o') => 1
  ('j','u') => 1
```

Currently, to get both object, I could do an ad-hoc 2nd count with:

```
function compute_statistics(vocab_counter, n)
    ngram_word_counter = Dict{Tuple,Dict}()
    for (word, count) in vocab_counter
        for ng in ngrams(word, n) # bigrams.
            if ! haskey(ngram_word_counter, ng) || ! haskey(ngram_word_counter[ng], word)
                ngram_word_counter[ng] = Dict{String,Int64}()
                ngram_word_counter[ng][word] = 0
            end
            ngram_word_counter[ng][word] += count
        end
    end
    ngram_counter = Dict{Tuple,Int64}()
    for ng in keys(ngram_word_counter)
        ngram_counter[ng] = sum(values(ngram_word_counter[ng]))
    end
    return ngram_word_counter, ngram_counter
end
```

Or concurrently update both `ngram_word_counter` and `ngram_counter` at the first loop:

```
function compute_statistics(vocab_counter, n)
    ngram_word_counter = Dict{Tuple,Dict}()
    ngram_counter = Dict{Tuple,Int64}()
    for (word, count) in vocab_counter
        for ng in ngrams(word, n) # bigrams.
            if ! haskey(ngram_word_counter, ng) || ! haskey(ngram_word_counter[ng], word)
                ngram_word_counter[ng] = Dict{String,Int64}()
                ngram_word_counter[ng][word] = 0
            end
            ngram_word_counter[ng][word] += count
            ngram_counter[ng] += 1
        end
    end
    return ngram_word_counter, ngram_counter
end

ngram_word_counter, ngram_counter
```

But I'm getting a `KeyError`, when updating `ngram_counter`:

```
KeyError: key ('b','r') not found
```

I've added an additional check and it worked:

```
function compute_statistics(vocab_counter, n)
    ngram_word_counter = Dict{Tuple,Dict}()
    ngram_counter = Dict{Tuple,Int64}()
    for (word, count) in vocab_counter
        for ng in ngrams(word, n) # bigrams.
            if ! haskey(ngram_word_counter, ng) || ! haskey(ngram_word_counter[ng], word)
                ngram_word_counter[ng] = Dict{String,Int64}()
                ngram_word_counter[ng][word] = 0
            end
            if !haskey(ngram_counter, ng)
                ngram_counter[ng] = 0
            end
            ngram_word_counter[ng][word] += count
            ngram_counter[ng] += 1
        end
    end
    return ngram_word_counter, ngram_counter
end

ngram_word_counter, ngram_counter
```

[out]:

```
(Dict{Tuple,Dict}(Pair{Tuple,Dict}(('b','r'),Dict("brown"=>1)),Pair{Tuple,Dict}(('t','h'),Dict("the"=>2)),Pair{Tuple,Dict}(('o','w'),Dict("brown"=>1)),Pair{Tuple,Dict}(('z','y'),Dict("lazy"=>1)),Pair{Tuple,Dict}(('o','g'),Dict("dog"=>1)),Pair{Tuple,Dict}(('u','m'),Dict("jumps"=>1)),Pair{Tuple,Dict}(('o','x'),Dict("fox"=>1)),Pair{Tuple,Dict}(('e','r'),Dict("over"=>1)),Pair{Tuple,Dict}(('a','z'),Dict("lazy"=>1)),Pair{Tuple,Dict}(('p','s'),Dict("jumps"=>1))…),Dict{Tuple,Int64}(Pair{Tuple,Int64}(('b','r'),1),Pair{Tuple,Int64}(('t','h'),1),Pair{Tuple,Int64}(('o','w'),1),Pair{Tuple,Int64}(('z','y'),1),Pair{Tuple,Int64}(('o','g'),1),Pair{Tuple,Int64}(('u','m'),1),Pair{Tuple,Int64}(('o','x'),1),Pair{Tuple,Int64}(('e','r'),1),Pair{Tuple,Int64}(('a','z'),1),Pair{Tuple,Int64}(('p','s'),1)…))
```

**Is there a way to concurrently sum the inner dictionary in the Dict{Tuple, Dict{String,Int64}} in a single loop?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if this answers the question, but you can make `compute_statistics` cleaner as follows:

```
function compute_statistics(vocab_counter, n)
    ngram_word_counter = Dict{Tuple,Dict{String,Int}}()
    ngram_counter = Dict{Tuple,Int}()
    for (word, count) in vocab_counter, ng in ngrams(word,n)
        ngram_word_counter[ng] = get(ngram_word_counter,ng,Dict{String,Int}())
        ngram_word_counter[ng][word] = get(ngram_word_counter[ng],word,0)+count
        ngram_counter[ng] = get(ngram_counter,ng,0)+count
    end
    return ngram_word_counter, ngram_counter
end
```

(this uses `get` to avoid `haskey` and shorter `for` syntax)

Another way to get `ngram_counter` calculated from `ngram_word_counter` is:

```
ngram_counter = map(x->x[1]=>sum(values(x[2])),ngram_word_counter)
```

or

```
ngram_counter = Dict(k=>sum(values(d)) for (k,d) in ngram_word_counter)
```

Comment: Oops. Confused `getkey` with `get`, but it's fixed now